# ¿Como modificar los mensajes de un input validation? en Angular

Tags: angular, angular5, angular6

Tomo como ejemplo este:

El **html**

```html
<div class="md-form">
  <input mdbInputDirective type="text" id="nombre" class="form-control" formControlName="nombre">
  <label for="nombre">Nombre</label>
</div>
```

El **ts**:

```
this.crearForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  nombre: new FormControl('', [
    Validators.required,
    Validators.minLength(4),
  ]),
});
```

**Como se ve tiene 2 validaciones**:

1- cuando es requerido, este envía el msj: **wrong**

2- cuando requiere mínimo 4 caracteres, este también envía el msj: **wrong**

Cuando todo esta correcto envía el msj **success**.

**¿Como puedo modificar cada uno de los mensajes?**

Es decir:

1- cuando es requerido, este envíe el msj: **Campo requerido**

2- cuando requiere mínimo 4 caracteres, este también envíe el msj: **Mínimo 4 caracteres**

Cuando todo esta correcto envíe el msj **Correcto**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes crearte un servicio con una función que puedas utilizar para saber si el valor de cada campo del formulario es válido y regresar el mensaje de error correspondiente

> Crear un servicio ***validator.service.ts***

```
import { Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup} from '@angular/forms';
@Injectable()
export class ValidatorService {

    public errorMessage: string;
    /**
     * @summary Usada para saber si un campo es valido o no
     * @param _field FormControlName ==> campo a validar
     * @param _form FormGroup ==> Formulario al que pertenece el campo a validar
     * @return boolean => true: válido | false = inválido
     */
    public isValid(_field: string, _form: FormGroup): boolean {
        if (_form.get(_field).invalid && _form.get(_field).touched) {
            if (_form.get(_field).errors.required) {
                this.errorMessage = "Campo requerido";
                return false;
            }
            if (_form.get(_field).errors.minlength) {
                this.errorMessage = "Mínimo" + _form.get(_field).errors.minlength.requiredLength + " caracteres";
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

> En tu módulo:

1. Importar el servicio
2. Agregarlo en providers

`import { ValidatorService } from './_services/validator.service.ts';`

`providers: [ValidatorServicice]`

> En tu componente:

1. Importar el servicio
2. Inyectar el servicio en el método constructor

`import { ValidatorService } from '../../../../_services/validator.service.ts';`

`constructor(public _validator: ValidatorService) {}`

> En tu vista:

```
<form [formGroup]="fgTest">
    <div class="md-form">
        <input mdbInputDirective type="text" id="nombre" class="form-control" formControlName="nombre">
            <div *ngIf="!_validator.isValid('nombre', fgTest)">
                <span style="color: #f4516c;">
                    {{ _validator.errorMessage }}
                </span>
        </div>
        <label for="nombre">Nombre</label>
    </div>
</form>
```

Cabe señalar que de esta manera se implementó solo para mostrar un mensaje de error, el primer mensaje de error que encuentre.

O la otra opción es hacer en la vista parte de las validaciones que hace la función ***isValid*** y replicarlo por cada elemento de tu formulario.

Answer (score 5):

Segun dice en https://angular.io/guide/form-validation se pueden diferenciar los mensajes en la vista segun el error

```
 <div *ngIf="nombre.errors.required">
    Nombre requerido.
 </div>
 <div *ngIf="nombre.errors.minlength">
    Nombre debe tener al menos 4 caracteres.
 </div>
```